# module import path not found

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

I'm using `React` context to handle user authentication globally.

I've implemented `useAuth` function inside `AuthContext.ts`  which gets the current context.
When I'm trying to use it like in `Auth.ts` a compile error returns

following error:

> ./src/contexts/AuthContext.tsx
> Module not found: You attempted to import ../../server/controller/firebaseConfig which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.

`AuthContext`:

```
import { auth } from '../../server/controller/firebaseConfig';
import { 
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
    signInWithEmailAndPassword,
    signInAnonymously,
    signInWithPopup,
    GoogleAuthProvider,
    FacebookAuthProvider,
    GithubAuthProvider,
    onAuthStateChanged,
    User
}
from 'firebase/auth';
import { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const AuthContext = createContext({
    user : null as User|null,
    error : '',
    isPending : false,
    methods : {
        register : (email : string, password : string) => 
        createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth,email,password),
        login : (email : string, password : string) => 
        signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth,email,password),
        signInAsGuest : () => signInAnonymously(auth),
        googleLogin : () => signInWithPopup(auth, new GoogleAuthProvider()),
        facebookLogin : () => signInWithPopup(auth, new FacebookAuthProvider()),
        githubLogin : () => signInWithPopup(auth, new GithubAuthProvider())
    }
});


export const useAuth = () => useContext(AuthContext);
```

`Auth`:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import 'bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css';
import { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { useAuth } from '../contexts/AuthContext';

export default function Authenticate() : JSX.Element {
    const { user, error, isPending, methods } = useAuth(); // error here

    const email = useRef() as React.MutableRefObject<HTMLInputElement>;
    const password = useRef() as React.MutableRefObject<HTMLInputElement>;
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

    return  <></>
```

}

Glad for any help

Comment: as the error suggests `Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.` it is what it is. Try to move that folder in src

Comment: I get it, but my import is in the server's folder. Is there a way/trick to fix it without changing the file location?

Comment: I want to keep my configuration file in the server folder and make it work somehow

Comment: you should not use any server files for your front-end project as they serves different purpose. just add new folder in your react src named config and copy the file.Why are you making things complicated? . Suppose you've to deploy your project. how are you going to reference those files?

Comment: Ok, but I'm handling requests on the server(GET, POST...) to store the data in Firestore with Nodejs. So, how could I "reunite" the config in the server and client?

Comment: Any help, please? I don't know where and how to use my firebase config. because, as I said, the firestore is being used in the server folder and firebase auth in the client(react src folder).